# Vuetify Data-Table, how to save or access which columns are sorted in which manner (asc, desc or not sorted at all)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetify-datatable

I have a Data Table with 50 columns, users can switch on off columns using checkboxes, now for example, if I sort one or multiple columns (asc or desc) and then check off some of these columns and then I forget what columns in which order. Now to get this information, I tried with reading the DOM with queryselectorall but this will only give the result of the columns which are already on display but I also need to know for the columns not in display as well.

If there any possible way that whenever we try to sort any column and we update this information or to access this by clicking a button.

Well apart from trying with queryselectorall, I do not have any code to share. However, I tried certain solutions with @update:sort-by and with @current-items="current", but didnt get any far.

Comment: Why is `@update:sort-by` not work for you?

Comment: @Moritz, for me it didnt work, if you have a work around, can you share please ?